# SpriteKit visual Editor bounding box not changing size

Tags: xcode6, sprite-kit

In the SpriteKit visual editor for sks files when changing the size of scale of a Color Sprite the bounding box size doesn't appear to change with it.

The green rectangle appears to be correct when resizing an the sprite but when switching between edit mode and simulate mode the green box updates to what is happening when playing the game (in the attached image).

Objects are colliding with the bounding box that doesn't match the sprite shape. The sprite is pinned and is not dynamic or affected by gravity or rotatable.

[image]

This is happening in Xcode 6.4 but didn't seem to happen in previous versions of Xcode.